# is it ok to use the ingress-nginx nodeport to access the cluster in production?

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

Im trying to set up a simple k8s cluster on a bare metal server.

Im looking into ways to access the cluster.

Ive been looking though the docs and read through the bare metal considerations section.

so far i've found setting external IP's and nodePorts aren't recommended.
Ive heard metalLB should be used in production so i was about to go ahead with that.

Then i realised the ingress is already using a nodePort service and i can access that for development purposes.

Could i just use this in production too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can. If you do not need **routing rules** or anything beyond what kube-proxy can offer, you don't need ingress controller like MetalLB.

Comment: thanks, was getting confused as to why i would need a load balancer to basically load balance the clusters internal load balancer.